# Make asynchrone request

Tags: java, android, json, web-services

I am getting json string from Restful web service with this code

```
WebService webService = new WebService("http://192.168.1.2:8080/data/resources/converter.user/");

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
String response = webService.webGet("123333",params);

 //Use this method to do a HttpGet/WebGet on the web service
    public String webGet(String methodName, Map<String, String> params) {
        String getUrl = webServiceUrl + methodName;

        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> param : params.entrySet())
        {
            if(i == 0){
                getUrl += "?";
            }
            else{
                getUrl += "&";
            }

            try {
                getUrl += param.getKey() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(param.getValue(),"UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();


            i++;
        }

        httpGet = new HttpGet(getUrl);
        Log.e("WebGetURL: ",getUrl);

        try {
            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Groshie:", e.getMessage());
        }

        // we assume that the response body contains the error message
        try {
            ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Groshie:", e.getMessage());
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

i get what i want but i want to know , if this method is synchron or asynchron ? application will be blocked when the request is running or web service will be called in backgroud ?

I founded this methode in stackoverflow, and there is too much unneeded code; I dont use parametres, is there an easier way ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can pull the foreach loop out of the code block if you don't use parameters.

As for the (a)synchronicity of the code, it depends on who is calling it. If you create multiple threads that each create their own instance of this class and then call webGet(), then it is asynchronous. If you have a main method that does nothing but call this and return, then that would be synchronous, and it would block.

Possible cleaned up code :

```
WebService webService = new WebService("http://192.168.1.2:8080/data/resources/converter.user/");

String response = webService.webGet("123333");

//Use this method to do a HttpGet/WebGet on the web service
public String webGet(String methodName) {
    String getUrl = webServiceUrl + methodName;

    httpGet = new HttpGet(getUrl);
    Log.e("WebGetURL: ",getUrl);

    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Groshie:", e.getMessage());
    }

    // we assume that the response body contains the error message
    try {
        ret = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Groshie:", e.getMessage());
    }

    return ret;
}
```